# Let $f: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ given as $f(t,y)$. How I understand:"$f$ has continuous partial $y$-derivatives"?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology

Suppose I have a function $f: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ given as $f(t,y)$.

Then how should it be understood "$f$ has continuous partial $y$-derivatives" ?

Should it be understood as I can write $y(t) = (y_1(t), \ldots, y_n(t))$ and then write $f(t,y(t)) = f(t,y_1(t),\ldots, y_n(t))$.

Then the $y$-partial derivatives are given as ? Should I just differentiate with respect to $y_1$, keeping everything else constant ?

Answer (score 2):

It means that if you consider $f(t,y_1,\dots,y_n)$, the partial derivatives $\partial f/\partial y_i$ exist and are continuous for all $i=1,\dots,n$. The first line of your question is really wrong. You are considering a composite function $F(t) = f(t,y(t))$; this is a function of $t$ only.